# Could symmetric keys be of sizes other than 2^x or 2^x + 2^y?

Tags: encryption

Is this an issue for, perhaps, RSA? I wonder if a key could be any other size, say 261 bits.

Comment: RSA is not a symmetric cipher.

Comment: @grawity I wanted to know if symmetric keys could be of any size. I brought up RSA to see if it had to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Modern CPUs are typically 64-bit. This gives us a very good performance incentive to design symmetric cryptography with block size as a multiple of this.
There is a lesser (IMHO) drive for using $2^x$ bits, many parts especially in hardware will require `ceil(log(length))` time/depth/gates by using $2^x$ we get more efficient implementations. 
Obviously we could build a less efficient (bytes/second or bytes/$) cipher with arbitrary block size.

Comment: What if it was a stream cypher?

Comment: Stream ciphers have a key size and an internal state size as well, and these are also essentially always of size 2^x bits for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible confusion here to be wary about. **The key size is not necessarily related to the *block* size.**

#### I. About the block size

Most of the case this is the case:

- Rijndael has a block size of 128 bits ($2^7$) and key sizes such as 128 bits, 192 bits and 256 bits (respectively $2^7, 2^7 + 2^6, 2^8$).
- idem for Twofish... and most of AES competitors.

However the era of block-cipher is coming to an end.

> Imagine there's no block ciphers, it's easy if you try :-)
>   *Joan Daemen - FSE 2017*

By that it means that we are more likely to see permutations and sponge-based crypto than block-ciphers.

Examples:

- Keyak has a state size of 1600 bits ($25 \times 64$)
- NORX-64 has a state size of 1024 bits ($16 \times 64$)
- Ketje has a state size of 400 bits ($25 \times 16$)
- ASCON has a state size of 320 bits
- Spongent has a state size of 384 bits
- ...

We are further away for the traditional $2^x$ bloc size. What matters is 
that it is a multiple of 32 (or 64 bits for high-end CPUs) so we are more like having a state size of $y \times 2^x$ rather than $2^x$ or $2^x + 2^y$.

As for the hardware requirement... Keccak $\chi$ operation can be seen as a 5-bit S-box. But it is extremely efficient in hardware. The reason is that it can be seen via bit slicing and thus be encoded with very few gates.

#### II. About the key size.

We have shown that key size are not necessarily related to the block size. 
Most of the time the key size will be a multiple of $32$-bit (4 byte). This is due to the structure of the CPU and the format of the data when sent.

There are few exceptions. Obsolete DES (and TDES-EDE) key size is effectively 56 (112) bits but seen as 8 (16) bytes with a parity bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See for example [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)), which allows the key size to be any number of bits between 32 and 448.